# add 3rd party libraries into intelliJ plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, findbugs

I am using findbugs plugin and creating custom detector in findbugs.
packing the messages.xml,findbugs.xml and the class of my detector, the thing is that my detector is using 3rd parties ,and when I run findbugs I get an error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

probably because the third party is not part of my intelliJ plugin.
How can I add third parties into intelliJ plugin ?
should I use manifest ? where can I find that manifest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right - you will have to add your custom FindBugs detectors in the settings dialog of the [FindBugs-IDEA plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/3847-findbugs-idea). Go to *File → Settings → Other Settings → FindBugs-IDEA* and press the green '**+**' icon. In the drop-down box, select *Install plugin from disk*, and choose the archive with your custom FindBugs detectors. In the screenshot, the fb-contrib detectors are installed:

[image: FindBugs Config Dialog]

Information on how to write and package custom FindBugs detectors can be found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/findbugsproject/findbugs/3.0.1/findbugs/src/doc/AddingDetectors.txt).